# Model binder data issue from a EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I'm showing in a List in a Razor view. In it I have several Editor templates that are displayed in the list view. Here is my editor template.

```
@using Contoso.MvcApplication.Extensions
@model Contoso.MvcApplication.ViewModels.MultipleChoiceQuestionViewModel

<h5>@Model.Question.QuestionText</h5>

<div>
@Html.RadioButtonForSelectList(m => m.Question.SelectedAnswer, Model.AnswerRadioList)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Question.SelectedAnswer)
</div>
```

The issue is where I set the `RadioButtonForSelectList`, it's binding so so, because I know at this situation should be inside a for loop like this:

```
@Html.RadioButtonForSelectList(m => m[i].Question.SelectedAnswer, Model.AnswerRadioList) // the index
```

But from the Editor template, I have no way to know the index inside a lambda expression.

This is the site where I copied the html extension from:

http://jonlanceley.blogspot.mx/2011/06/mvc3-radiobuttonlist-helper.html

And here is the view model that I'm using

```
public class MultipleChoiceQuestionViewModel
{
    public MultipleChoiceQuestion Question { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> AnswerRadioList { get; set; }
}
```

How do I correctly bind the radioButton?

When I read the tag in code, all the models in my list have the same id: `Question.SelectedAnswer`. I assume this is wrong, because there should be an indexed ID like so:  `Question.SelectedAnswer.[INDEX]`.

UPDATE:

```
    public ActionResult Index(short testId)
    {
        GenerateQuiz(testId);
        StartQuiz();

        return View(CreateQuestionViewModel((MultipleChoiceQuestion)CurrentQuestion));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MultipleChoiceQuestionViewModel q)
    {
        // Save answer state
        ((MultipleChoiceQuestion)CurrentQuestion).SelectedAnswer = q.Question.SelectedAnswer;

        if (CurrentNumber == Questions.Count - 1)
        {
            QuizCompleted();
            return RedirectToAction("ShowResults");
        }
        else
        {
            NextQuestion();
            return View(CreateQuestionViewModel((MultipleChoiceQuestion)CurrentQuestion));
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, you have multiple questions and want to add a foreach to display them in the view? Not sure if I understand, could you clarify please?

Comment: The last razor view is an EditorTemplate. Yes, I have multiple questions and I'm showing one by one through my controller.. let me better show you the code

Answer (score 0):

The part of the view that displays the questions should look like this:

```
@for (int j = 0; j < Model.Questions.Count; j++)
{
    <h5>
         Model.Questions[j].QuestionText
    </h5>
    <div>
       @Html.RadioButtonForSelectList(m => m.Questions[j].SelectedAnswer, Model.AnswerRadioList)
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I also though in that way, but I cannot do that because Questions could have several templates (FreeResponse, MultipleChoice, etc.). That's the reason why I'm using EditorTemplates